# Convert String to ItemStack java bukkit

Tags: java, string, casting, bukkit

I am working on a bukkit plugin and am trying to save a whole inventory in a file. So I saved the file in a String using: 
    InventoriesData.set(player.getName(), ItemStack + "");

but now it is saved as a String, I don't know how to convert it back to an ItemStack.
I know I can save all the data seperate aswell but I want to save all the information and think it should be possible to convert back. So does anybody have a clue on how to do that?

it will return this btw: 
    ItemStack{BLAZE_ROD x 1, UNSPECIFIC_META:{meta-type=UNSPECIFIC, display-name=Inventory Selector, Current:2, enchants={THORNS=3}}}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make an itemstack, you need to have the material and the amount:

```
String s = /* your material string */;
Material m = Material.matchMaterial(s);
ItemStack stack = new ItemStack(m, 1);
```

However, note that `ItemStack` is `ConfigurationSerializable`, meaning you can simply save it directly to a config:

```
ItemStack is = /*...*/;
getConfig().set("example", is);
is = (ItemStack) getConfig().get("example");
```

Inventories are contextual, hence them being unserializable. If you wanted to, you could make a helper class to track the armor, and non-air (`null`) stacks as a class, and then make that class itself `ConfigurationSerializable`:

```
@SerializableAs("Inventory")
public class SInventory implements ConfigurationSerializable {

    private final List<ItemStack> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ItemStack head;
    private ItemStack chest;
    private ItemStack legs;
    private ItemStack boots;

    /* Other fields */

    public SInventory(Map<String, Object> config) {
        List<ItemStack> items = (List<ItemStack>) config.get("inventory");
        for (ItemStack item : items) {
            if (item != null) {
                this.items.add(item);
            }
        }
        this.head = (ItemStack) config.get("head");
        this.chest = (ItemStack) config.get("chest");
        this.legs = (ItemStack) config.get("legs");
        this.boots = (ItemStack) config.get("boots");
    }

    public static SInventory valueOf(Map<String, Object> config) {
        return new SInventory(config);
    }

    public static SInventory deserialize(Map<String, Object> config) {
        return new SInventory(config);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> serialize() {
        Map<String, Object> back = new HashMap<>();
        back.put("inventory", this.items);
        back.put("head", this.head);
        back.put("chest", this.chest);
        back.put("legs", this.legs);
        back.put("boots", this.boots);
        return back;
    }
```

The `Map<String, Object>` is the section that represents this inventory. So if you save a `List<ItemStack>` under the string "Inventory" when you pass it via `serialize`, then you can retrieve it from the map like so:

```
List<ItemStack> inv = (List<ItemStack>) map.get("Inventory");
```

This usually leads to a much simpler and easier-managed system.

Comment: well this information helps, but i still don't know/understand how I can serialize the ItemStack, could you explain it a but further?

Comment: ItemStack is already serializable. You simply either set or retrieve (via `Configuration.get("key")`) the value and cast it.